# How to call an AngularJS defined service method?

Tags: angularjs

I'm studying AngularJS and I reached [this section](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#dependencies) but I couldn't understand how come the `batchLog` service is called this way !

The `batchLog` service is defined to have a single, no-args method called `log`.

Yet the `routeTemplateMonitor` service utilizes the `batchLog` service through this statement:

```
batchLog($route.current ? $route.current.template : null);
```

How come is this statement supposed to call the `log` method that also has no arguments ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should notice that there is a function returned from batchLog factory which actually accepts an arguement message. Here the arguement sent in is being consumed by the function which is returned from batchLog factory.